# R batch forecasting negative values

Tags: r, batch-processing, forecasting

I am running a loop on multiple timeseries. As i received negative forecasts, I was advised to use `Lambda=0` in order to adhere strictly to positive forecasts.

If I do this for 1 time series, it works perfect. From the moment I do this in a loop it runs in error. The error i receive is:

> Error in pegelsresid.C(y, m, init.state, errortype, trendtype,
>   seasontype,  :    NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)

The R code is:

Data of the TimeSeries is:

```
StartYear<-2011

StartMonth<-1

DataTimeSeries.ts <- ts(DataTimeSeries, frequency = 12,start=c(StartYear,StartMonth))



     1121407 H 650270 14144690 17155531 500054691 H 650230
Jan 2011      17        0        6        8         0        0
Feb 2011       5        0        6        5         0        0
Mar 2011      19        0        2        0         1        3
Apr 2011       7        0        2        3         5        7
May 2011       7        0        3       26         3        5
Jun 2011       3        0        1        1         0        0
Jul 2011      10        3        4        2         0        0
Aug 2011       9        1        3        1         0        0
Sep 2011      14        0        5        8         2        7
Oct 2011      17        0       11        6         1        0
Nov 2011      11        1        2        2         0        0
Dec 2011      75       12      131        0         0        3
Jan 2012      13        1        3        2         1        7
Feb 2012       8        0        5        2         0        0
Mar 2012      14        0        3        4         0        0
Apr 2012       8        0        1        6         0        0
May 2012       8        0        4        2         0        0
Jun 2012      11        0        6        0         0        0
Jul 2012      10        3        5        3         0        0
Aug 2012      10        1        6        5         0        0
Sep 2012      16        0        5        3         0        0
Oct 2012       3        0        2        0         0        0
Nov 2012      14        1        2        2         1        0
Dec 2012      11       46        5        0         1        0
Jan 2013       7        1        1        2         0        2
Feb 2013       9        1        5        2         0        0
Mar 2013      17        0        6        1         0        0
Apr 2013       8        0        3        0         0        0
May 2013      17        2        2        4         0        0
Jun 2013       1        1        2        0         0        0

ns <- ncol(DataTimeSeries.ts)
rows <-nrow(DataTimeSeries.ts)


Forecast <- matrix(NA,nrow=h,ncol=ns)

for(i in 1:ns) 
  Forecast[,i] <- forecast(DataTimeSeries.ts[,i], lambda=0,h=h)$mean
```

If I run the forecast without lambda=0, then the forecast is (= negative values):

```
    [,1]       [,2]        [,3]        [,4]       [,5]       [,6]
 [1,]   9.887062  4.4379429   3.1059891  0.24696736 -0.3792315 -0.5448469
 [2,]   8.951653  0.3544301   2.2218957  0.04790458 -0.4395805 -0.6557000
 [3,]  10.787565 -1.8823119   4.6116380 -0.15115820 -0.4999294 -0.7665531
 [4,]  12.802994 -3.9683800   6.5737599 -0.35022098 -0.5602784 -0.8774062
 [5,]   7.916042  0.3676410  -1.0954609 -0.54928376 -0.6206273 -0.9882593
 [6,]  75.723475 26.5071178 117.7545308 -0.74834654 -0.6809763 -1.0991124
 [7,] -23.604058 -1.3480372 -26.4102628 -0.94740932 -0.7413252 -1.2099654
 [8,]   6.693199  3.0567211   4.2765418 -1.14647211 -0.8016742 -1.3208185
 [9,]  16.689538  0.5293152   2.0234525 -1.34553489 -0.8620231 -1.4316716
[10,]   5.771219 -0.9780367   0.9339003 -1.54459767 -0.9223721 -1.5425247
[11,]   9.055315  2.4255619   2.2734174 -1.74366045 -0.9827210 -1.6533778
[12,]   4.120385  2.5818660   1.9924763 -1.94272323 -1.0430700 -1.7642308
```

Can somebody help me on this one?

Ok thanks for the info , i added the data and the code appropriately now.

Comment: Could you provide a minimum working example of your issue? In particular, could you provide code that could be run in an R console that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: Dataframe looks as follows:

Comment: The formatting got messed up.  If you select the whole span of your data and click the "{}" button on the toolbar of the edit window it should cure it...

Comment: ok thanks for the info. I changed the data and the code to get the formatting correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your data contains zeros and you cannot take logarithms of zeros.

You could add a small positive constant to all data before taking the transformation, and then remove the constant from the forecasts.

Comment: Is it ok just to add for example 0.000001 to all the history (also the non-zeros), and after the forecast to detract that again from the history. I presume this is the best way for the forecast. If the value is small enough i assume that correcting the forecast is not necessary then?

Comment: is it a good method to automatically define lambda in this case by using: Lambda[,i] <- BoxCox.lambda(DataTimeSeries.ts[,i])

Comment: Sorry to downvote, but this advice is dangerous. If all observations are positive, `ets()` (I'm using `forecast` 8.2) can fit multiplicative models, and these can leverage up to produce exploding forecasts. Someone found that out the hard way here: [Extreme peaks if forecasting slow movers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312197/1352). Much better to use a dedicated method for forecasting intermittent demands (yes, I know that [Croston's method has problems](https://doi.org/10.1002/for.963)).